# Codeigniterのルーティングについて

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter の `/application/config/routes.php` のルーティングに `$route['(:any)']` を設定すると、 `$route['404_override']` が動かなくなってしまうので治したいです。

Comment: それはつまり `(:any)` では条件が緩すぎる、ということになるかと思います。`(:any)` を使うことにした理由やマッチさせたいURLの例、逆に404にしたいURLの例を挙げていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: やはりそうですよね。
:anyはやはり辞めるということになったので解決いたしました。どうもありがとうございました。